# Attempted to lazy load [user] on model [App\Models\Tweet] but lazy loading is disabled despite me using eager loading

Tags: php, laravel

I have this fetch function, it fetches the full feed if no user is selected, and it fetches a specific user's feed if it is.

```php
public function fetch(): void
{
    if ($this->userToShowFeedFor == null) {
       $this->tweets = Tweet::with('user')->withCount('likes')->get();
    } else {
       $this->tweets = $this->userToShowFeedFor->tweets;
    }
}
```

in my blade template I have this:

```php
@if (!$userToShowFeedFor)
      <a wire:navigate href="{{ route('userpage', ['user' => $tweet->user]) }}"
         class="text-gray-600 cursor-pointer underline">u/{{ $tweet->user->username }}</a>
@else
    <p class="inline text-gray-600 ">u/{{ $tweet->user->username }}</p>
@endif
```

Despite using the `with('user')` I am still getting this error.

[image]

I even used tinker to make sure I wasn't doing any bad SQL queries under the hood and it looks all good.

[image]

Comment: have you tried this in the else ?  $this->tweets->load('user');

Comment: where is this `fetch` method being called? show what ever code you use to get the data you pass to the view

Answer (score 0):

Check in your app the istruction `Model::preventLazyLoading`, tipically is set in the *boot* method of the *AppServiceProvider* class.
If it is set, when you try to lazy load a model, an exception is throwed.

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#preventing-lazy-loading) the documentation

Comment: I added that myself and indeed removing it gets rid of the error but I wanted to know why that showed up in the first place.

Comment: Have you checked that you are using eager loading even when  *$this->userToShowFeedFor is not null*?

Answer (score 0):

i think the runtime code is different than u expected i think it hits the else case  on that exception to can you try to add `load('user')` to at the end to be like that

```php
public function fetch(): void
{
    if ($this->userToShowFeedFor == null) {
       $this->tweets = Tweet::with('user')->withCount('likes')->get();
    } else {
       $this->tweets = $this->userToShowFeedFor->tweets->load('user');
    }
}
```

load works the same as  with but it is lazy eager load that works after you get the result  you can check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)